# _foo.mustache.haml templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, mustache

I would like to use a single haml/mustache template, like this:

```
.foo
  %h2 {{title}}
```

That I can render two ways:

1) As a partial and passing a hash:

```
render :partial => 'foo', :mustache => {:title => 'hello world'}
=>
<div class='foo'><h2>hello world</h2></div>
```

2) As a partial without a hash for use  inside a script tag:

```
:javascript
  render :partial => 'foo'
=>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  <div class='foo'><h2>{{title}}</h2></div>
</script>
```

I've tried various combinations of file names... "_foo.mustache.haml", for example, however rails won't recognize that extension.

Also, I'm using the mustache_template_handler.rb from ryan bates:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/295-sharing-mustache-templates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, this works -- but it's not real template chaining (is that even possible?!)

```
module MustacheTemplateHandler
  def self.call(template)
    haml = "Haml::Engine.new(#{template.source.inspect}).render"
    if template.locals.include? :mustache
      "Mustache.render(#{haml}, mustache).html_safe"
    else
      haml.html_safe
    end
  end
end
ActionView::Template.register_template_handler(:mustache, MustacheTemplateHandler)
```

Comment: so this only works for `_foo.html.mustache` ? not for `_foo.html.mustache.haml` ?

Comment: also, how can I access the helpers in rails such as `link_to`, `image_tag` and other custom defined helpers?

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it works, very limited though. Do you guys know how to chain handler? so *.mustache.haml would actually work.

Comment: another big problem - how to use partials. "= render" doesn't work, and {{> partial_name}} returns that the file is not found, even though i tried all possible combinations of path/name.

Comment: if you change this line: `haml = "Haml::Engine.new(#{template.source.inspect}).render"` to `haml = "Haml::Engine.new(#{template.source.inspect}).render(self)"` allows access to rails helpers! I don't quite understand why it works, but it does...